# Autodesk forge/viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have eported IFC model from Revit. I use Your IFC exporter, and there are some issues when I view model in ACC or BIM 360, or Viewer: In BIMVision seems all correct, but in Your viewers are very bad graphics: There are some IFCOpeningElements etc in view. There are "messy" model lines too.... Model is exported in global coordinates, so there are very uneven lines. Can You advice my, how to view IFC file right ?

Regards, Milan

[ACC viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Ivg.png)

[BIMVision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbrzK.png)

Comment: Don't know what your IFC format is, but which conversion method you're using? You may try to switch between the modern and legacy conversion method to compare the difference. For the IFC4 model, it's recommended to use the modern one. See `advanced.convesionMethod` of the output setting here for details: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure

Comment: IFC2x3 2.0. Screen is from ACC, so there is no option to change conversion method.

Comment: Ok, for the ACC product problem, I would advise you to consult [ACC support](https://construction.autodesk.com/support/). Unfortunately, we cannot help from the Forge side unless you translate the IFC yourself following the above method I shared. Sorry

Comment: To clarify, the ACC viewer is built on the top of Forge Viewer, but it's managed by the ACC product team.

Comment: Another approach is that you may try to upload it to Forge, translate the IFC with Forge model derivative API using the modern IFC conversion method and use Forge Viewer to see If it’s reproducible. If it is, please consider providing a non-confidential reproducible model to forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com for investigations.